# WKWebView didCommit not calling when uploading file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

In my app there's a `WKWebView` that loads a page that contains an input field to upload files to my server.

I have the following code in my app:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        networkActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
```

This will show a network activity indicator while a webpage is loading.

For some reason, this isn't called when I start uploading the file. This will get called when uploading the file is ready:

1. I select a file and tap to submit/upload the file.
2. The file upload starts (this may take a while), `WKWebView didCommit` doesn't get triggered.
3. File upload is ready and the webpage reloads. Now `WKWebView didCommit` gets called.

Why doesn't `WKWebView didCommit` get called as soon as I submit my form to upload the file?

Comment: Newest stable, or beta? Please, specify version numbers.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov I'm using iOS `13.5.1 (17F80)` stable version and `Xcode 11.5 (11E608c)` stable version.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Is the behavior I described a bug or is this expected because only downloading/opening a website will trigger `WKWebView didCommit`?

Comment: you can although trigger `startAnimating` when you do the right before `webView.load(REQUEST)`

Comment: also, you could find [WKUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate) useful and especially an [Upload Panel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1641952-webview{ func. I don't see full context, so just guessing.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Same behavior on an iOS 12.4 simulator. So it's not a bug.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Yes, there's a fully loaded webpage with input filed.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov I already do call `startAnimating` before `webView.load(REQUEST)` but this has nothing to do with it, since `webView.load(REQUEST)` is only needed the first time I'm loading the WKWebView, not when browsing on the loaded page.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov BTW: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1641952-webview is only available for `macOS` not for `iOS`.

Comment: Thanks! There are still so many things to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `startAnimating()` to `WKWebView decidePolicyFor` like this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        networkActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```